# How do I help my team hire a Tech Support Analyst?

Tags: job-search, job-satisfaction, job-listing

I am in Technical Support, or User Services as we call it. I'm very grateful for my job. I work at a top-tier research university, on a government grant, and I get to help researchers who are trying to use an enormous cloud infrastructure my team has built, that supports cancer research and is part of the cancer moonshot project. The job is aligned with my interests, it pays enough, I enjoy doing it, and I find it meaningful. I do not want to leave, and I don't think I will want to leave, ever. I have two systems administrators on my team who feel the same way about their jobs.

We've been looking for people to add to our team. I'm not the hiring manager; I am not the recruiter (we are using one); I am a team member. It's been a very frustrating process for me to interview people. Because there seems to be a prevailing attitude in tech (supported by some of the comments on this question), that tech support is just a stepping stone to a development or sysadmin position. Our interviewees do not seem to want to stay in tech support. Others see it as a dead-end job.

The people I have interviewed have the following three characteristics which make it impossible for me to recommend them to be hired:

1. **Wrong emphasis:** interviewees have been more interested in building things and fixing problems than interacting with users and learning about their problems, and taking their feedback and feeding it back into development plans for the product.
2. **Poor emotional intelligence:** they are not passing the empathy-oriented part of the interview.
3. **Lack of interest:** when given the opportunity, they ask, essentially "how long do I have to be on your team and how soon can I get out and do something else that I would rather be doing?".

I'm trying to help my team find the right candidate because the candidates we've seen so far have not been even close, and we are getting desperate for help.

**What can I, or my team, do to find the right tech support candidate?** Should we be looking someplace in particular?

**Is the job title wrong?** We've changed titles from Tech Support Analyst to Tech Support Engineer. That has only seemed to attract more people who would rather be system administrators.

**What is important to put in the job description**? Should we say that we are looking for someone who wants to stay in tech support and enjoys interacting with people? Should we downplay the technical skills and hope they can pick them up? The job is supposed to be fairly generalist, it will focus on IT but may bleed over into questions regarding our data and bioinformatics systems.

**Maybe when people think Tech Support they think help desk and helping people fix their printers?** How can we convey that this is less hardware-focused and more software- and people-focused?

**EDIT:** This question was put on hold because it was too broad. I edited it, and received only one person's feedback on the updates. Neither that person nor the others removed their flag; and their complaints about the question still say that it doesn't have an answer. I am sure it does. I think there is a better answer out there than "go out there and find people who don't like to be inquisitive". Because Tech Support is inquisitive. It's not just inquisitive about computers. It's also inquisitive about people and their needs. I think way too many people in the tech community are blind to that. Perhaps it's because they've been burned by help desk experiences that were run by scripts, or by co-workers who did not want to be there. But there are people who enjoy tech support. And they are not stupid, or dumb, or enjoy the mundane. To me, building and configuring computers all day is mundane. Mundane is in the eye of the beholder. And there are organizations out there that do tech support right.

Every user that flagged my post and provided no feedback or response on the modifications, even after I asked them for feedback, is a Software Developer according to their profile. Maybe they were too busy or forgot. But I am getting the feeling that they just don't like my question. I have a feeling that they just don't see why anyone in their right mind would want to stay in technical support. Why would anyone in their right mind stay a developer all their life? Or a sys admin? I think there are very good answers to these questions. And there is a good answer to my question. It's just not one of these two.

Comment: @GiveLove I've edited your question to cut down on length and identify some core questions that I believe can be answered properly here and voted to reopen your question. If you disagree with my edits and revert it, please see what else you can do to cut down on length or narrow the scope as even with my edit this is a pretty long post.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37444/discussion-on-question-by-give-love-how-do-i-help-my-team-hire-a-tech-support-an).

Comment: @Lilienthal: Thank you for editing. I've cut it down further. Yeah I think I put a lot because I was so frustrated with people looking at my job as mindless grunt work, that I felt I needed to explain myself and I why I don't  think that it is. But you are right, it's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Based on what you are describing I would avoid analyst or engineer in the job title.  "IT Support Technician" will draw fewer people who want to move towards an engineer or analyst position.  You can convey the focus is on software and people in the responsibilities section.  You could mention little about hardware and more about working with users to understand their goals and assist in achieving them.  I think you are looking for a unicorn but wish you well in your search.

Comment: Regarding the last two paragraphs - your question was closed by getting 5 close votes from users with 3k+ reputation. [For it to be reopened, 3k+ people will have to vote](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to reopen it. I genuinely respect all the work you've put in to improving it (I did remove a DV I cast early on), but I suspect it'll fall into the category of "asking for advice" which is also off-topic. Either way, you might want to [pop into chat](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) and ask them for more feedback/reopen votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking for a tech support person only but someone who is happy with mundane. A very though-sell. People who do techie stuff, do it because they are hungry for learning. Unfortunately, in the tech-support help desk, **fast** learning stops about 3 months or 6 months after the hire. You get to answer the same phone calls, about someone forgetting their password or not being able to connect to the network, etc issues. For an inquisitive mind, this is a flashing light, telling them get out and GET-OUT-NOW ! For those who will take this as a career path, are not the techie types in general. I suggest you find these people, doing some other mundane job, like flipping burgers at the local fast food joint and train them. Then pay them much better than their short order cook salaries. They will be happy to stay with you, doing the same thing over and again. Yes, training these people will take much longer term than a tech enthusiast, but at least the will not look into becoming developers or sysadmins and jump ship when opportunity arises.

Comment: I'm not sure where that idea is coming from, that tech support is mundane. There is a lot of learning in tech support. Learning about users needs, learning how others are using our system, passing this on to developers, helping us guide how our future development work. I get to participate in deciding how our system is built, at a high level. I see that many of the devs and sys admins are very siloed; they don't know what other parts of the organization are doing. I get to have a generalist, broad view of our operation. I really enjoy that.

Comment: I think you're a bit harsh with this person but you are right that he's probably cutting out a major segment of potential employees by having this very specific person in mind. Chances are he's very difficult to work with and expects everyone to follow a specific path. My advice to OP is open up a little and understand that most people would not show up to work if suddenly money was not a problem.

Comment: Believe me. I have been there. I did tech support about 2 years and wanted to drill my brains out after about 3 months. The pipeline may change and you may need to learn new things but not as fast as a developer or systems engineer has to. And technology enthusiasts thrive on information overload.

Comment: Let me ask you this Dan. Are you a developer, or a sys admin?

Comment: I am a full time developer and was a sys admin at one point during college.

Comment: How would you feel Dan, about hiring someone on your team, who did not want to be a developer and kept asking at interview how soon they can become e.g. a project manager?

Comment: I would ask them why did they apply to a developer position then tell them I'd call them in 2 weeks. However in your answer you're simply saying you don't have qualified interviewees and you're asking how to find one. The answer is it's very hard. There are plenty of people who claim to be a dev and expert at a language who can't even put together a working application when asked. So finding qualified person is difficult especially in any tech field. Your question and statement do not match and I do not know how to help you. As you say in tech support, "Need more information from customer."

Comment: It's not about finding qualified interviewees. You were saying, I think, in your earlier comment, that I am cutting out a whole swathe of people who might be qualified for the job. I am basically cutting out people who don't want the job.

Comment: I kinda resent this answer saying that Tech support is not for techie types.  Although I am not doing it now tech support can be a great career.  My first support job a 100 years ago sent me to a one week class on transact SQL  and since then every job I have had involved me doing DBA work.  Unless you are working in a organization where you follow a script there is always a change to learn new things and get better at your job.  And the reason I left my last support job?  Because the focus was on ticket closing without caring if the problem was solved and the user satisfied.

Comment: @JasonJanowitz Thank you. You see, in many organizations people look at "tickets" as a nuisance. As people whom you just wish would go away. People look at complaints as a nuisance and a cost. And they forget that feedback, criticism, is a GIFT. It is a gift. It is valuable.

Comment: @JasonJanowitz my point exactly. Tech support is and will always be the stepping stone for the techie types, not a career path. And yes as most tech support jobs focus on the metric and the metric is how many tickets you closed in a day/week/month. I have had short lived positions that you were expected to close X number of tickets every week, otherwise considered as under-performing. No the way to treat someone whose main focus is problem solving and complex ones at that.

Comment: @MelBurslan: I find this offensive, just so you know. I intend to stay in tech support for the rest of my life. Are you saying that it makes me a loser?

Comment: @GiveLove, how long have you done Tech Support and how long do you intend to do that job? Most big companies prefer people to have career paths and move on to higher level jobs. Look up the Peter Principle if you need a reference on where this can go wrong yet I suspect more than a few companies apply that principle in some form or other.

Comment: @JBKing: I work at a university. I have also worked at a biotechnology company. I don't know how things will pan out in the future, but right now I feel like I want to die working on this job. And I have a couple of system administrators on my team who feel the same way about their jobs. I'm telling you, it's amazing.

Comment: @GiveLove, I hope you do a better job of understanding questions in your job than you did with mine as I don't believe they were that hard to answer in my opinion. I've been a web developer for 17 years but somehow I doubt many saw that coming in 1993 when I started university.

Comment: "I intend to stay in tech support for the rest of my life.". Not only that, you also want your hire to stay in that position for the rest of their life as well. Or, at least, for a very long time without any career growth. Good luck! You are going to need that.

Answer (score 4):

Let's twist the question--how can you make a tech support job a more attractive long-term career path? What opportunities do you offer for career growth? Training? Do you have a path where someone can eventually take on more responsibilities? How do you foster the tech support community? Do you host meetups or participate in conventions?

Or ... do you offer flexible work arrangements? Exceptional benefits? Work from home?

There are plenty of people who are interested in jobs that offer security, decent wages and comfort. I've personally worked with people who were happy to bus tables in a casino until they retired. The casino offered decent wages and union protection--both very attractive if you don't have a easily marketable skill.

You can find people in all the usual places IF the job has some redeeming qualities. It sounds like you're having trouble finding someone to take a job that doesn't offer much.

Comment: I think in our case the job is actually quite attractive. Not siloed; closely knit team; meaningful project. No scripts. Smart users. Research environment. Opportunities to learn about cancer and health and genomics and bioinformatics. Maybe even opportunities to participate in standards-setting. Opportunity to buy a single family home within biking/walking distance to work. Things like that. I really think this is one of the best tech support jobs out there, but that's just my own perspective.

Comment: How much of that is obvious from the outside? Silos, teams and project are things you get to know when you're on the inside, and those are very subjective (not to mention corporate). What attracts your average guy who just wants a paycheck and no hassles? Great pension? Job guarantees?

Comment: That's something you try to figure out in the interview, right? That's the soft stuff that can't be captured in a job posting.

Comment: Sure! Advertise the benefits in the posting and get people who are motivated by those benefits.

Comment: Where do I advertise? We've been trying and all we are getting is people who are not interested in tech support.

Comment: @GiveLove - most likely you are getting people who are interested in tech support as a stepping stone in their career, which is something you seem to look down on. I'm sorry, but very few technical people are happy to be stuck in a rut, even if you don't seem to view it as such. You're making the mistake of trying to make the world make sense within your own narrow definition, and getting frustrated that others will not meet your expectations. Instead, accept the world for what it is and try to find the best fit according to those realities (like the fact that ppl will not be as passionate)

Comment: @AndreiROM: I understand what you mean. And I do need to be aware of that, that not everyone wants to die a tech support person. But I don't want to be with someone who all but says in the interview "how soon can I get off your team". I've edited my question to be more specific. Will you please remove your off-topic flag? Or does it still seem off-topic to you?

Comment: It seems like all of these issues--generating enthusiasm in the interview, finding where to post--are about knowing your target audience. Give people a title they can feel proud about ("customer support supervisor"?), and a few breadcrumbs along the path to show progress toward a goal. Or some unbeatable benefit that makes other people turn a little green. Sell those in the adverts & interview. I'd advertise in the local papers and cragi's list--somewhere you can get a lot of responses. No one is staying in a job that doesn't make their chest swell a little when they discuss it.

Comment: We've been trying that but we don't know what that is. We had something like Network or Technical Support Analyst, which wasn't working that well. We changed that to Technical Support Engineer or something along those lines, to reflect the fact that we want the person to have some technical skills and be able to troubleshoot themselves without involving other purely-technical folks, but that has, I feel, only attracted more people who want to be sysadmins and dont' want to be in tech support.

Comment: "Technical" scares off people without programming/admin skills, and sounds too low level for someone who wants a technical role, which you're seeing. It is a tough balancing act, but a title that isn't technical and a job description that requires tech skills might work. The market for tech is really strong right now, so this won't be easy. Maybe even offering a path up and out makes sense.

Comment: Analogously, it almost feels like you're asking for where to find people who are passionate about working in retail. (high turn-over, lower educational requirements, stepping stone, not really most people's dream job, etc.) I really don't think comparing it to "what if you hired a dev that wanted to be a PM asap" is fair.

Comment: @Cat'r'pillar Retail is not a job. Sales is a job. You are confusing industry with job. One can do sales in things other than retail, e.g. be sales engineer at tech company. Just because you can't see why someone would want to do that, doesn't mean that there aren't many people out there who would enjoy that job. I have no desire to be a sys admin in the same way as many sys admins have no desire to be tech support people. I think it is entirely fair to compare this to Dev vs PM. 

I want people who are passionate about supporting users of cutting-edge research informatics infrastructure.